# Como receber um valor e guarda-lo na posição indicada pelo usuário em um array de arrays (matriz)?

Tags: java, matriz

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
int matriz[][] = new int[numLinhas][numColunas];

    //FOR PARA RECEBER OS VALORES E POSIÇÕES INFORMADAS PELO USUÁRIO
    for(int x=0; x<numLinhas; x++) {
        valor = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o valor que "
                + "deseja adicionar: "));
        valorLinha = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a posição "
                + "que deseja adicionar(linha):"+"["+numLinhas+"]["+numColunas+"]"));
        valorColuna = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a posição"
                + "que deseja adicionar(coluna):"+"["+numLinhas+"]["+numColunas+"]"));  
        for(int i=0; i<numLinhas; i++) {
            if(i == valorLinha) {
                for(int j=0; j<numColunas; j++) {
                    matriz[i][j] = valor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Até funciona, porém com matrizes pequenas.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver seu problema basta inserir o valor para cada iteração do loop nas coordenadas ma matriz. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
int matriz[][] = new int[numLinhas][numColunas];

//FOR PARA RECEBER OS VALORES E POSIÇÕES INFORMADAS PELO USUÁRIO
for(int x=0; x<numLinhas; x++) {
    valor = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o valor que "
            + "deseja adicionar: "));
    valorLinha = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a posição "
            + "que deseja adicionar(linha):"+"["+numLinhas+"]["+numColunas+"]"));
    valorColuna = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a posição"
            + "que deseja adicionar(coluna):"+"["+numLinhas+"]["+numColunas+"]"));  

    // insira nas coordenadas informadas da matriz
    matriz[valorLinha][valorColuna] = valor;
}
```

Comment: Beleza, mas daí eu teria que verificar se a posição não está ocupada...Mas consigo fazer, obrigado

Comment: Na verdade, não funcionou, deu esse erro:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at br.edu.utfpr.exer03.Exer03.main(Exer03.java:35)

Comment: Isso acontece quando, ou `valorLinha`, ou `valorColuna` são maiores do que as dimenções da matriz.